# Inform Model of Incorrect Prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

I'm curious about what happens to a model when it hits the production stage and it begins to make predictions. Let's say 80% of these predictions are correct and 20% are incorrect. When it comes time to make more predictions, wouldn't it be problematic if the model selects rows that were previously false positives / incorrect?

Or at this stage would you retrain and hope the model has learned enough to avoid the wrong predictions?

Comment: Anyone have any helpful tips regarding this, or is my last sentence the solution here?

Comment: Maybe [tag:active-learning]?